# Why SBT doesn't use resolvers from root project (in multi-module project)

Tags: sbt

In a multi-module project, SBT doesn't seem to use `resolvers` when building modules. The resolvers are declared in the root project's `build.sbt` as follows:

```
resolvers += "SpringSource Milestone Repository" at "http://repo.springsource.org/milestone"
```

and the projects are declared like:

```
lazy val core = project.settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= { ... }
)
```

But when compiling, the resolvers are not used and I get :

```
[info] Resolving org.springframework.scala#spring-scala;1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT ...
[warn]  module not found: org.springframework.scala#spring-scala;1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/ariskk/.ivy2/local/org.springframework.scala/spring-scala/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/scala/spring-scala/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-scala-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.springframework.scala#spring-scala;1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the following in the root project's `build.sbt`:

```
resolvers in ThisBuild += "SpringSource Milestone Repository" at "http://repo.springsource.org/milestone"
```

`in ThisBuild` is the answer. See [Scopes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Scopes.html).

Comment: Newer sbt versions use this syntax: `ThisBuild / resolvers += "SpringSource Milestone Repository" at "http://repo.springsource.org/milestone"`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a Scala / ScalaJS project.

The resolver was only taken when added to the 'sub-project'.

```
//this works NOT
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")

// this works
lazy val client = (project in file("client")).settings(
   scalaVersion := scalaV,
   ...,
   resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots"),
   ...
```

(sbt 0.13.15)